# pgnscid error message

Tags: database, pgn, scid

I have been downloading zip files from "The Week In Chess"'s site and converting them to a scid database.  I get quite a few `Error reading move in game...: O-O` errors.  It appears that scidvspc correctly imports the move.  Any idea on what is causing the error message when reading a king or queen side castle?

Comment: It would help the question if you gave a pgn which demonstrates this problem

Comment: @ian It would have also helped my troubleshooting if I had actually played through a couple of games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the first failure was because it was an illegal move:

```
[Event "2nd Gurgaon Open 2014"]
[Site "Gurgaon IND"]
[Date "2014.01.03"]
[Round "4.6"]
[White "Shivananda,B"]
[Black "Grover,S"]
[Result "0-1"]
[WhiteTitle "IM"]
[BlackTitle "GM"]
[WhiteElo "2331"]
[BlackElo "2478"]
[ECO "C00"]
[Opening "French"]
[Variation "Reti (Spielmann) variation"]
[WhiteFideId "5007038"]
[BlackFideId "5021103"]
[EventDate "2014.01.01"]

1. e4 e6 2. b3 d5 3. Bb2 dxe4 4. Nc3 Nf6 5. g4 h6 6. Qe2 Nc6 7. Nxe4 e5 8. O-O-O
Be6 9. Bg2 Nd5 10. Qd3 Ndb4 11. Ne2 Nd4 12. Nxd4 exd4 13. c3 Nc6 14. Ng3 Qg5 15.
Nf5 dxc3 16. Bxc3 h5 17. h3 O-O-O 18. Qe3 Ba3+ 19. Bb2 Qf6 20. Qc3 Nd4 21. Nxd4
Bxb2+ 22. Kxb2 Rxd4 23. g5 Qf4 24. Qe3 Rhd8 25. Qxf4 Rxf4 26. Rhf1 Rd3 27. f3
Rd5 28. h4 Rdd4 29. Kc3 g6 30. Rde1 Rxh4 31. Rh1 Rhf4 32. Re3 Rd5 33. Bh3 Bxh3
34. Rxh3 Rxg5 35. Kd3 Kd7 36. Re4 Rxe4 37. fxe4 Rg4 38. Ke3 h4 39. Rh1 Rg3+ 40.
Kd4 0-1
```

It never occurred to me that you could get by with an illegal move in a tournament game.

The others appear to be because they are Chess960 games.

Comment: From what's here it's difficult to say whether it was an illegal move, or a mistake in the recording of the moves, or a mistake in the reporting of the moves. To be honest I would suspect the second to be the most likely

Comment: So far, I found 4 more tournament games (not Rapid or Blitz) that had illegal castling.  They have involved moving the rook or king from its original square then back to its original square then castling.